# How do I call an Array constructor initializing the Array length?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

How do I make a constructor to set the length of a global array?

I have already tried several ways to do it, none successful.

Example:

```
public Class{

    public Class(int length){
       double[] array = new double[length]; <- this is not global

       L = length;
    }

   int L;
   double[] array = new double[L]; <- this does not work
}
```

I need an array with a length determined by Constructor.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: What about declaring `double[] array` outside of the constructor and then creating the object `array = new double[length];` inside the constructor?

Comment: just as a marginal remark: You should not name your class Class

Comment: I believe you should read about object oriented programming in Java, these are really basics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's as simple as this:

```
public class MyClass{
    double[] array;

    public MyClass(int length){
        array = new double[length];
    }
}
```

I've also made the code actually *compile* :)  You were missing some keywords etc.

If you want to access `length` in your code, use `array.length` rather than storing it redundantly in a separate field.

Also calling your class `Class` is a bad choice, even as an example, because it clashes with `java.lang.Class`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class aClass{
    //define the variable name here, but wait to initialize it in the constructor
    public double[] array;

    public aClass(int length){
        array = new double[length];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the array as member variable. Then initialize it in the constructor.

```
public class A{    
    private double[] array;    
    public Class(int length){
        array = new double[length];  
        L = length;
    }    
}
```

You could initialize it in second way. But then you need to use a fixed length

```
public class A{    
    private double[] array = new double[100];  // use fixed length  
    public Class(int length){
        array = new double[length];   
        L = length;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve but why you don't simply do it this way:

```
public class Class{
    public Class(int length){
        this.array = new double[length]; // <- this is not global
    }
    double[] array;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it

```
public  class Test  {
 double[] array;

      public Test  (int length){
          array = new double[length]; <- this is not global


}
```

Comment: Please correct the code , you have never defined a `class` here and also the choice of `Class` as classname is incorrect as it clashes with `java.lang.Class` !

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Thankyou. Did'nt realize.